# How keyboard input is handled in kde, gnome, unity and lxde? What are differences in similarities

Tags: gnome, keyboard, kde, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with a closed-source app and tech support is unhelpful. The problem manifests in incorrect handling of keyboard input if app is started with non-english kb layout active and in this case remains even if I switch to english kb layout. I recall that in far past I used unity desktop and there was no problems, but Unity isn't officially supported anymore... So I need an idea of what mechanisms are involved.

I tried KDE docs, but I didn't find much on internals. They proably are there, but poorly structured and hard to find. I really need to at least understand what kde components are involved, bonus points for providing picture how events travel and transform before they are passed to application.

Comment: I read your question a few times. `incorrect handling of keyboard input` is a bit broad. What non-english layout is used and what goes wrong, exactly?

Comment: @Adriaan I use en/ru mixed layouts. A few games I play under Ubuntu do not recognize kb. shortcuts when started with ru layout even after global layout is switched to en.

Comment: This would suggest that your closed source app is doing it's own keyboard mapping. I'd contact the authors.

Comment: @Adriaan They say it's not their fault, so I'm stuck here. Besides, with Unity desktop things work fine.